# d3.js drop down menu on click

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I want to create a simple drop down menu in d3. I know there are many examples online but I could not find an example that produces a drop down menu ON CLICK instead of having a menu permanently on screen. 
I have a simple scatter plot and when I click on one of the dots, I want a drop down menu to appear. At the moment I have working code where on "mouseover" a tooltip appears. To the same function I want to add the on click drop down menu. 
Here is the relevant code so far (excl drop down menu):

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 3.5)
  .attr("cx", xMap)
  .attr("cy", yMap)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(cValue(d));}) 
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      tooltip.transition()
           .duration(200)
           .style("opacity", .9);
      tooltip.html(d.TITLE)
           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

    })
```

Now I want to add the drop down menu on click. I have managed to get a drop down menu on screen permanently by adding:

```
<select id = "opts">
<option value="ds1">data1</option>
<option value="ds2">data2</option> 
<option value="ds3">data3</option>
 <!-- and so on... -->   
 </select>
```

But I only want the menu to appear when I click on a point on the graph.
I am very new to d3 so any feedback is appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an on click event that selects your drop-down by its is and moves it just like the tooltip. Your css should look like this

```
#opts{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Then add an on click function to your svg dots

```
.on("click", function(d){
    d3.select("#opts")
      .style("display", "block")
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
});
```

Comment: sorry I havent been able to respond. thanks for your feedback, I tried this and nothing seems to be displayed on the screen at all? And if I were to be able to use this code where do I add my options and how would I do this? sorry for the very late response! appreciate your feedback